# Pandas groupby mode every n rows

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas df that I am trying to groupby every 3 rows and get the mode. How can I do this?

Example:

```
time                       a                       b
0                          0.5                    -2.0
1                          0.5                    -2.0
2                          0.1                    -1.0
3                          0.1                    -1.0
4                          0.1                    -1.0
5                          0.5                    -1.0
6                          0.5                    -1.0
7                          0.5                    -3.0
8                          0.5                    -1.0
```

Should be:

```
time                       a                       b
2                          0.5                    -2.0
5                          0.1                    -1.0
8                          0.5                    -1.0
```

Comment: How about rolling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `mode`:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3).agg(lambda x: x.mode().to_numpy()[-1])

   time    a    b 
0     2  0.5 -2.0
1     5  0.1 -1.0
2     8  0.5 -1.0
```

The output here may differ from your expected output in some cases if it is possible to have more than one mode.

I should also mention that you may not want to use mode on data that is not categorical nature (this includes floating point data). Consider factorizing your column first or you may have inaccurate results due to floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: Time may very well be the index. In general, I feel grouping by `np.arange(len(df))//3` is a safer choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `mode` from `statistics` module for aggregation:

```
from statistics import mode

df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3).agg({'time': 'last', 'a': mode, 'b': mode})
```

Output:

```
   time    a    b
0     2  0.5 -2.0
1     5  0.1 -1.0
2     8  0.5 -1.0
```

In Python 3.8 `mode` returns the first mode encountered. Formerly, it raised `StatisticsError` when more than one mode was found.