# Pandas: Groupby with group size limited, based on rank of items

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find a way to group the following DataFrame such:

1. I `df.groupby("Strike")`, but limit the groupsize to 2.
2. In the case of groupsize > 2 (as in the example below), I would want the largest (+) grouped with the largest (-) *based on the Size column*, and so on until there are no more pairs left.
3. Lastly, for the grouping, each (+) needs an opposing (-). [preventing index 3 & 6 from being grouped]

Note:

1. The order may not be as clean as in the example below, so relative positioning won't work as an approach.
2. The below example is a subset of a larger dataframe fwiw.

| Index | Size | Strike | Structure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 170 | 1.8 | (+) |
| 1 | 140 | 2.8 | (+) |
| 2 | 62 | 2.8 | (-) |
| 3 | 170 | 1.82 | (+) |
| 4 | 170 | 2.82 | (+) |
| 5 | 120 | 2.82 | (-) |
| 6 | 170 | 1.82 | (+) |
| 7 | 140 | 2.82 | (+) |
| 8 | 62 | 2.82 | (-) |

Desired output:

| Index | Size | Strike | Structure | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 170 | 1.8 | (+) | 1 |
| 1 | 140 | 2.8 | (+) | 2 |
| 2 | 62 | 2.8 | (-) | 2 |
| 3 | 170 | 1.82 | (+) | 3 |
| 4 | 170 | 2.82 | (+) | 5 |
| 5 | 120 | 2.82 | (-) | 5 |
| 6 | 170 | 1.82 | (+) | 4 |
| 7 | 140 | 2.82 | (+) | 6 |
| 8 | 62 | 2.82 | (-) | 6 |

I was trying to use ["Size"].rank() as my approach, but I got stuck trying to then re-assign group numbers based on the descending "Size"

Thx!

Comment: Hopefully, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59110612/pandas-groupby-mode-every-n-rows) may help.

Comment: Unfort not, as that’s based on relative positioning (ie, every 3rd element).  I can’t guarantee the positioning of mine

Comment: It would be helpful to add df.to_dict() to your question, so other people can easily reproduce your example. Also, just to make sure, when you say " the largest", that's defined by the `Size` column, isn't it?

Comment: Oh you’d prefer the dictionary copy-paste for the data vs markdown?

Comment: And sorry, yes defined by size column.  I’ll make that edit.

Comment: I haven't came up with a solution myself, but I was thinking that if you can group and then sort, by size the solution from that post could work. Still there's the problem of ensuring one (+) and one (-) per group. Sorry if I'm adding confusion, just trying to brainstorm a bit.

Comment: Any help is appreciated!  Yeah the group and sort is exactly what I was trying too.  I think if you sort, the use size.rank() on another groupby((Strike, Structure)) it gets you really close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being somewhat complicated, so I am not entirely sure the logic is correct, but here is an attempt.  I will break it down with explanation, but the full code is in a block below.

*Note this approach depends on the column `Index` being present - if it is actually the DataFrame index, you will need to do something like `df.reset_index()`.*

**First**, separate the data into the "plus" and "minus" segments:

```
plus = df[df['Structure'] == '(+)'].copy()
minus = df[df['Structure'] == '(-)'].copy()
```

**Second**, assign a descending grouped rank to each, based on the `Strike` column:

```
plus['Rank'] = plus.groupby("Strike")["Size"].rank("first", ascending=False)
minus['Rank'] = minus.groupby("Strike")["Size"].rank("first", ascending=False)
```

**Third**, merge the two subsets, based on `Strike` and `Rank`.

```
cols= ['Strike', 'Rank', 'Index']
merge = plus[cols].merge(minus[cols], on=['Strike', 'Rank'], how='outer')
```

The merge needs to be an outer merge, such that the rows from both `plus` and `minus` are all included.  This should pair items with the same `Strike` and `Rank`, and all pairs will be a `(+)` and `(-)` observation paired together.  Observations without a pair will still be included, but will have `NaN` values for their missing counterpart.  The `Index` column is included in the merge, as this will be necessary assigning the group labels back to the original DataFrame.

It is probably helpful to show what this `merge` looks like:

```
   Strike  Rank  Index_x  Index_y
0    1.80   1.0        0      NaN
1    2.80   1.0        1      2.0
2    1.82   1.0        3      NaN
3    2.82   1.0        4      5.0
4    1.82   2.0        6      NaN
5    2.82   2.0        7      8.0
```

Here, the index (i.e. `merge.index`, the pandas DataFrame index object) has the group labels.  The `Index_x` and `Index_y` are products of the merge, but they provide a linking back to the rows of the original DataFrame.  The `Strike` and `Rank` columns show what each group is capturing.

**Fourth**, create a Series for linking the `Index` column values to their group labels.  This concatenates all the values from `Index_x` and `Index_y`, and takes the corresponding group assignment based on the `merge.index`.

```
mapper = pd.concat([merge['Index_x'], merge['Index_y']]).dropna()
mapper = pd.Series(mapper.index, mapper)
df['Group'] = df['Index'].map(mapper) + 1
```

Here is the final result:

```
>>> df 
   Index  Size  Strike Structure  Group
0      0   170    1.80       (+)      1
1      1   140    2.80       (+)      2
2      2    62    2.80       (-)      2
3      3   170    1.82       (+)      3
4      4   170    2.82       (+)      4
5      5   120    2.82       (-)      4
6      6   170    1.82       (+)      5
7      7   140    2.82       (+)      6
8      8    62    2.82       (-)      6
```

There is a slight difference from your expected output in the order of group labels - but the group assignments are the same.  There may be an additional sort which can be added to get your exact output, but for now I'm assuming that's not required.

Thanks for the challenging question!

---

Full code:

```
plus = df[df['Structure'] == '(+)'].copy()
minus = df[df['Structure'] == '(-)'].copy()

plus['Rank'] = plus.groupby("Strike")["Size"].rank("first", ascending=False)
minus['Rank'] = minus.groupby("Strike")["Size"].rank("first", ascending=False)

cols= ['Strike', 'Rank', 'Index']
merge = plus[cols].merge(minus[cols], on=['Strike', 'Rank'], how='outer')

mapper = pd.concat([merge['Index_x'], merge['Index_y']]).dropna()
mapper = pd.Series(data=mapper.index, index=mapper)
df['Group'] = df['Index'].map(mapper) + 1
```